# Does mono support classic ASP?

Tags: linux, asp-classic, mono

I am looking for a solution to run a (old) web application written in classic asp on a Linux server.

Is this possible with mono or does it only support **ASP.NET**?

If it's not possible with mono are there other solutions?
I've read about Chilisoft and the Sun Java system webserver (which was renamed by oracle to the Oracle Iplanet Webserver) but it seems I can't download that products anymore.

Comment: Mono and .Net are nothing really to do with old 'classic ASP'. Mono is a cross platform runtime for .Net.

Comment: FYI, iplanet is one of the earliest names for that server, it went: "netscape webserver" -> "iplanet" -> "sun one webserver" -> "sun java webserver" -> "sun java system webserver" -> "iplanet".

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't. But [Oracle iPlanet Web Server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/iplanetwebserver-098726.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen) does, and it seems to be available under BSD licence now.

Answer (score 2):

Mono is designed for ASP.NET applications. Refer Link 
http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility